# What is coskewness and how can it be calculated?

Tags: moments, skewness

I would like to calculate coskewness of two random variables. However I couldn't find even basic information on this matter. Is there a standard definition? How to calculate it? If not what are my alternative options? Is it possible to have a normalized coskewness like correlation coefficient?

Thanks

Comment: I found [this paper](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/statistics_refs/CoskewnessAndCokurtosis.pdf) through Google. Is it not what you want?

Comment: I have read that paper. It is more focused on tensors than skewness itself.

Comment: OK, just thought it would be useful; it did seem to have a definition. Good luck!

Comment: [This paper](http://www.econ.sinica.edu.tw/upload/file/20071130.pdf) has a valid definition. Page 6 eq.(5).

Answer (score 6):

[In this paper](http://www.econ.sinica.edu.tw/upload/file/20071130.pdf) coskewness is defined as
$$
coskew_{i,m} = \frac{COV(r_i,(r_m-\mu_m)^2) }{E[(r_m-\mu_m)^3]}.
$$
You can calculate it by using the standard moment estimators - that's what I would do.
Thus, given a sample for market returns $(r_m^j)_{j=1}^N$ and asset returns $(r_i^j)_{j=1}^N$ you calculate the quantities for each sample pair and do the calculation.

Comment: I actually looked at this paper as well. I am trying to understand the asymmetric nature of the formula. I do not wish to compute with respect to a benchmark (i.e. market in this example), but rather to two asset returns. In this case you have a different result depending on where you put the square at the nominator.

Comment: If I find the right reference then I will post it later. I guess you are interested in a portfolio context? Then it makes sense to capture the contribution of an asset to the portfolio skewness (this is what is meant by co-skewness). Then you could replace $r_m$ by the return of the portfolio (in this setting when you have already included the new asset, I think).

Comment: @Cagdas Ozgenc Maybe [this paper](http://docs.edhec-risk.com/mrk/000000/Press/EDHEC_Publication_Optimal_HF_Allocation.pdf) of EDHEC contains more info for what you are looking for.

Comment: No I would like to have coskewness of two assets not portfolio.

Comment: Why do you need that? Coskewness to a portfolio makes clear sense, to the market too - but what should coskewness between 2 assets be? Maybe this is why you don't like the asymmetry.

Comment: There is no paper apparent at the link: could you please provide a citation and, if possible, a working link?

Answer (score 3):

**Is there a standard definition?**
Yes, these quantities were defined in

> Kraus, A., Litzenberger, R.H., 1976. Skewness preference and the valuation of risk assets.
>   Journal of Finance 31, 1085-1100.

**How to calculate it?**

Check page 6 of the following document

http://asianfa2012.mcu.edu.tw/fullpaper/10312.pdf

**what are my alternative options?**

Depends on what information you need.

**Is it possible to have a normalized coskewness like correlation coefficient?**

Yes, in page 6 of the aforementioned document the autors say

> More recent studies use standardised measures of co-skewness and co-kurtosis (Harvey and Siddique, 2000; Monero and Rodríguez, 2009), which are better behaved, with less extreme observations and smaller variance ...

Answer (score 1):

This link might help you get a clearer idea: http://www.quantatrisk.com/2013/01/20/coskewness-and-cokurtosis/

It includes the mathematical definition along with a Matlab implementation.